How to transition height 0 to auto without max-height but with PURE CSS
This is probably a question many of you have had and for some reason the fix isn't easy to find.
But there is a fix!
Allow me to show:
First you need to create a grid element with the following css:


<div class="grid-element">
</div>

<style>
.grid-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition-property: grid-template-rows;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
</style>



Now add the content-wrapper inside the grid-element:


<div class="grid-element">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- here comes your content to slide down -->
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.grid-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition-property: grid-template-rows;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.content-wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
}
</style>



Now the content will still be hidden to allowed the slidedown to work you'll have to add the conditional class slidedown-active with the following css grid-template-rows: 1fr;
In this example i add and remove the class with a button but you can apply this slidedown anyway you want and put anything inside the content-wrapper that you want to slidedown.


<button onclick="toggleSlidedown()">toggle slidedown</button>

<div class="grid-element">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- here comes your content to slide down -->
    <p>hello world!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.grid-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition-property: grid-template-rows;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.content-wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: red;
}

.slidedown-active {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
</style>

<script lang="js">
function toggleSlidedown() {
  const element = document.querySelector(".grid-element");

  if (element.classList.contains('slidedown-active')) {
    element.classList.remove("slidedown-active");
  } else {
    element.classList.add("slidedown-active");
  }
}
</script>




stackoverflow is not a personal blog

Oh wow it has been answered only need to scroll down 13 answers lower! Very easy to find.

@TemaniAfif its not, its meant to be a place where programmers can easily find answers to their problem. And right now this solution is not at all easy to find! But maybe formatting my question as a tutorial was not right I will edit it but I highly disagree with the duplicate question!

It took me 5 seconds to find the duplicate question that contains the exact same answer you provided so (1) it's easy to find and (2) your question (which is not a question) is a perfect duplicate

Ofcourse you are someone that is obviously a hardcore SO user, but people who actually want to find this fix will definitly look hours on hours bro its the 13th answer thats objectively and factually not easy to find. I can format my question differently but you can't be serious about it being easy to find.... Or do you think people will press ctrl + F and type in 'grid-template-rows: 0;' in when they look this up?

and what make you think your question/answer will be easier to find? It won't. The other question is the 1st result on google and it's not that hard to spend a few seconds scrolling. If scrolling is something you consider hard then no one will find your answer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The solution is a grid!


<button onclick="toggleSlidedown()">toggle slidedown</button>

<div class="grid-element">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- here comes your content to slide down -->
    <p>hello world!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.grid-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition-property: grid-template-rows;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.content-wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: red;
}

.slidedown-active {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
</style>

<script lang="js">
function toggleSlidedown() {
  const element = document.querySelector(".grid-element");

  if (element.classList.contains('slidedown-active')) {
    element.classList.remove("slidedown-active");
  } else {
    element.classList.add("slidedown-active");
  }
}
</script>



